How do I correctly save abbrevs?
I defined a global abbrev, then thought that I better make it a local one, so I wanted to save the abbrevs, then edit abbrev_defs accordingly. So I used abbrev-edit-save-buffer, then opened abbrev_defs and got a nice scare when the file was empty except for the top line! Luckily, I'm using btrfs and had system snapshots I could take the file from. Then I tried the same thing, defining an abbrev using add-global-abbrev, then using abbrev-edit-save-buffer in a variety of conditions, including without init, and it always had the same result: replacing my a,abbrev_defs with a file empty except for the top line. Yet, if I define an abbrev, then quit Emacs and agree to save abbrevs, it adds the defined abbrevs to abbrev_defs as it should. So clearly, I'm not supposed to use abbrev-edit-save-buffer like that. But using define-abbrevs doesn't seem to change abbrev_defs at all. So what exactly am I supposed to do to save my abbrevs to abbrev_defs?

See Saving Abbrevs in the Emacs manual.

What is the value of abbrev-file-name? Are you sure you are checking the correct file? If I do (setq abbrev-file-name "/tmp/foo_abbrev_defs"), then M-x list-abbrevs, then in the *Abbrevs* buffer, I do M-x abbrev-edit-save-buffer, I find all my global abbrevs (the only kind I have) in /tmp/foo_abbrev_defs. Don't forget to reset abbrev-file-name afterwards! Make sure you are doing M-x abbrev-edit-save-buffer from the *Abbrevs* buffer, not some arbitrary buffer.

It's only a guess, but it seems you are in the wrong buffer when you are running the command. Make sure you are doing M-x abbrev-edit-save-buffer from the *Abbrevs* buffer, not some arbitrary buffer.

Oh, I see, thanks, I thought I was supposed to run it from the buffer I defined the abbrevs in.
